# Is there a way to reuse schema document properties in another schema in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas which have repetitive `created` and `modified` properties. Is there a way in mongodb to reuse it instead of repeating same code over and over? Can't seem to find the right phrase to google search this.

Admin Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const AdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  companyId: {
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company',
  },
  created: {
    at: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    by: String,
  },
  modified: {
    at: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    by: String,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model('Admin', AdminSchema);
```

AdminPermissions Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const AdminPermissionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  companyId: {
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company',
  },
  label: String,
  description: String,
  created: {
    at: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    by: String,
  },
  modified: {
    at: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    by: String,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model('AdminPermissions', AdminPermissionsSchema);
```

Comment: This can be done with a plug-in. But mongoose also has such a functionality (update and created date) on board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose gives you the option to **timestamp** your documents during creation or update with `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties. Do this instead of using `created` and `modified`,

```
const AdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  companyId: {
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company',
  },
  createdBy: String,
  modifiedBy: String,
}, {timestamps: true}); //this is required

export default mongoose.model('Admin', AdminSchema);
```

And handle `createdBy` and `modifiedBy` separately. You can timestamp all you schema declarations like the one above.

Comment: cool :D So these timestamps are default UTC right? And then you just add your offset e.g +8 hours... depending on timezone?